# Django inline formset data not saved

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.11

I'm working in `Django 1.11`

I have three models, `business`, `business_address`, `business_phone` where `business_address` and `business_phon` are associated with `business`.

I want to create fields for `business_address` as well as `business_phone` along with `business` whenever a new business is added.

To achieve this, I have implemented `

**models.py**

```
class Business(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    business_type = models.ForeignKey(BusinessType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'businesses'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BusinessAddress(models.Model):
    business = models.OneToOneField(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'business_addresses'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.line_1, self.line_2, self.city, self.state)


class BusinessPhone(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=None)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'business_phones'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number
```

**forms.py**

```
class BusinessForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        exclude = ()

class BusinessAddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessAddress
        fields = '__all__'

class BusinessPhoneForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessPhone
        exclude = ()

BusinessAddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Business,
    BusinessAddress,
    form=BusinessAddressForm,
    extra=1,
    can_delete=False
)

BusinessPhoneFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Business,
    BusinessPhone,
    form=BusinessPhoneForm,
    extra=1,
    can_delete=False
)
```

**views.py**

```
class BusinessCreate(CreateView):
    model = Business
    fields = ['name', 'business_type']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(BusinessCreate,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            data['business_address'] = BusinessAddressFormSet(self.request.POST)
            data['business_phone'] = BusinessPhoneFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['business_address'] = BusinessAddressFormSet()
            data['business_phone'] = BusinessPhoneFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        business_address = context['business_address']
        business_phone = context['business_phone']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if business_address.is_valid():
                business_address.instance = self.object
                business_address.save()
            if business_phone.is_valid():
                business_phone.instance = self.object
                business_phone.save()

        return super(BusinessCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Business Added Successfully')
        return reverse('business:list')
```

and in **template.html**

```
<form action="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% form.as_p %}

  // address
  {{ business_address.management_form }}
  // business fields
  {% render_field business_address.form.line_1 %}
  {% render_field business_address.form.line_2 %}


  // phone field
  {{ business_phone.management_form }}
  {% render_field business_phone.form.phone_number %}
</form>
```

**But when I fill all details, only details of `business is saving in database and there is no record created for`phone`and`address` model and even there is no error.**

Answer (score 1):

You said that there is an error but you are not showing it in your question. The error (and the whole traceback) is more important than anything you wrote (except may be from forms.py and views.py)

Your case is a little bit trickier because of the formsets and using multiple forms on the same `CreateView`. There are not many (or not many good ) examples on the internet. Untill you dig in the django code how inline formsets are working you will have troubles.

Ok straight to the point. Your problem is that formsets are not initialized with the same instance as your main form. And when your amin form saves the data to the database the instance in the formset is not changed and at the end you do not have the ID of the main object in order to be put as foreign key. Changing the `instance` attribute of a form attribute after init is not a good idea.

- In normal forms if you chnage it after `is_valid` you will have unpredictable results.
- For formsets changing `instance` attribute even directly after init will do nothig, becase the forms in the formset are already initialized with some instance, and changing it after will not help.

The good news is that you can change attributes of the `instance` after Formset is initialized, because all forms's `instance` attributes will point to the same object after formset is initialized.

You have two options:

1. Instead of setting `instance` attribute if the formset, set only the `instance.pk`. (This just a guessing I have never do it but I think it should work. The problem is that it will look as hack).
2. Create a form that will initialize all forms/formsets at once. When it's `is_valid()` method is called all fomrs should be validated. When it's `save()` method is called all forms must be saved. Then you need to set `form_class` attribute of your `CreateView` to that form class. The only tricky part is that after your main form is initialized you need to initialize the others (formsests) with the `instance` of your first form. Also you need to set the forms/formsets as attributes of your form in order to have access to them in the template.

I'm using the second approach when I need to create an object with all it's related objects. This will separate business logic from view logic because from the view perspective you just have a form which can be:

- initialized with some data (in this case POST data)
- checked for validity with `is_valid()`
- can be saved with `save()` when it's valid.

You preserve the form interface and if you made your form correctly you can even use it not only for creating but for updating objects together with their related objects and the views will be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `business_address.is_valid()` returns False, probably because the business is not passed to the form and it complains that it is a required field.

Comment: if `business_address` wouldn't be passing to template then how, `business_address.form.line_1` is printing label as `Line 1` and so.

Comment: I tried printing some statement in `else` if `is_valid()` returns `false`, but it doesn't execute and no line was printed. It means, `is_valid()` is `true`

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `business_address.instance = self.object` why don't you just call 'business_address.save()`. Have you tried to step-by-step debug it and see what happens?